# properness of stack

Tags: stacks, ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,

assume we have an algebraic stack $A$ over $Sch(\mathbb{Z})$ which is quasi-compact and with separated diagonal. Assume that I have a stack $B$ which is obtained by rigidifying $A$ by a subgroup of the inertia group. Assume moreover that $A\rightarrow B$ is faithfully-flat and smooth over $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{d}]$ and that the diagonal of $B$ is finite.
Question : is $B$ proper over $\mathbb{Z}$, or at least over $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{d}]$ ?? If so is it trivial to prove it?

Comment: out of curiosity: what do you mean by rigidifying?

Comment: Is $A$ assumed to be proper?

Comment: @knob call this subgroup $G$ then $B$ is the stack with the same objects of $A$ but with $Hom_B(x,y):=Hom_A(x,y)/y^{*} G$ where the action is the composition action
@Keerthi Madapusi Pera I only have these hypoteses and $A$ is not proper

Comment: I think $A = B = \mathbb{A}^1$ is a counterexample.